# Is it OK to post a digital version of my resume on my personal site?

Tags: interviewing, resume

I have a personal site that lists out my technical projects, my technical blog, as well as my photography.  At the very bottom of the site I have a link to my "resume" - `myname.com/resume` - which is just a simple, digital version of my professional resume without any contact info listed.

**Pros:**

- I can go into a bit more detail and link to various things online (like my personal projects' websites or articles that were written about my impact).
- I can make it mobile-friendly for easy consumption
- It gives me an easy way to quickly send my resume to someone I meet.  The online version has a "PDF" version available as well.
- I can make it a tiny bit more visually appealing than a black-and-white.  Nothing that makes it depart from the typical resume format, just small visual improvements.

**Cons:**

- Strangers might be able to find it online (is that a con?)

What are some reasons why posting my resume in digital format to my personal site might be a bad idea?

Comment: It is your website, you can post whatever you want. If someone told you it was a bad idea to post your resume, they might probably also be able to tell you the reasons for saying so. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @MaskedMan - I'm not sure how I can be more clear.  `What are some reasons why posting a resume to a publicly accessible personal site would be a bad idea`

Comment: You are operating from a false premise as far as I am concerned. Someone told you something, and rather than asking them for the reasons, you are asking us, "why did someone say so?"

Comment: You could edit the online version and avoid disclosing certain details (e.g. censor the e-mail to avoid spam, etc.). Presumably legitimate visitors to that resume link already know how to contact you.

Comment: @MaskedMan the premise is irrelevant.  Remove it from your assessment.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, but I think you're focusing on the wrong pros and cons. Your html resume can have two versions, a public one and a private one. The public one can have the current employer edited out and/or your current position edited out (if you're worried about stalkers, ex-boyfriends/girlfriends, debt collectors, or your current employer finding out your resume is too up-to-date, which could mean you might be you're looking to jump ship assuming you're currently employed). Also, having a public site doesn't mean it needs to be using your full real name.

Comment: It could just use an abbreviation of your first name for instance. And yes, an advantage is that strangers are going to be able to find it. But you must think of your resume only as a part of an overall strategy. How are strangers going to find it? Why would they care? How can you make sure it's not just random strangers? For instance, if you set up a public version of your resume you may want to cultivate a professional persona that will make relevant people want to take a look at your resume. You could write a blog that follows your industry, participate in online professional forums, etc.

Comment: Also, if you're going to post your resume publicly anywhere, or give it out to random recruiters, if you're in the US, I'd suggest you use a free Google Voice number and a separate gmail account. Personally, I made the huge mistake of posting my cell phone number and email address three years ago along with my real resume on dice dot com (but for a brief 12 hours) and I am still getting irrelevant phone spam and email spam from recruiters that do not know the difference between Android and iOS, or between San Francisco and Florida, which makes it impossible for my spam filter to differentiate.

Answer (score 4):

> Strangers might be able to find it online (is that a con?)

Yes, it probably is a very big con - the internet is full of crazy people...

Luckily, you can have all the advantage of having a digital resume without worrying too much about your average crazy person looking up your current place of employment and (cyber)stalking you - don't put the link into your site footer, and only share to businesses you're actually applying to at the top of your tailored-to-the-position 2-page resume.. Make sure you set your robots.txt and sitemap configuration to stop spiders crawling your resume. If you want to be a bit clever, you can change the URL periodically.

Comment: +1 Hadn't thought about robots.txt. Gotta make a quick change. Cheers!

Comment: ...and keep in mind that someone can pull /robots.txt (it's a well-known location, after all) and specifically pull the URLs listed therein. robots.txt is an advisory, not a requirement of any kind, even though many well-behaved robots *will* comply with the requests therein.

Comment: The con of sending it to businesses you're applying to, with no other resume, is that they could just ignore it because they want an attached PDF resume. The not-so-big con of sending it with an attached resume is that they could just ignore it because they have an attached resume. There may be a time and place for an online resume, but I'm not sure where it is - maybe situationally on a business card, if the URL is typeable enough (although I'd probably opt for LinkedIn instead).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show off on your personal site, do so. The 'con' stated seems pretty far fetched to me, not something I have ever worried about anyway. It's really up to you what details you want on your site.